# three.js working on the web but not on my computer

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I have been trying to open the "webgl_loader_collada.html" on my computer but it displays nothing on the browser.

In fact, this source code is taken from the Three.js library download (http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/zipball/master).

The same code is working on:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you open the Javascript Console and tell us the error?

Comment: I do not know any javascript console. Could you please tell me which one to use in order to tell you? Currently, I am only copying the code in Notepeda++ and opening with google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons Chrome doesn't load local files from local websites. You can disable that by using the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Make sure there are no instances of Chrome running and launch Chrome like this:

On Windows:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

On MacOS:

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --allow-file-access-from-files %U
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser mrdoob. I added the line to the target in properties, restarted my chrome, however, the stuff is still not working :(

Comment: Oh, It's working!! Maybe it took some time :O!!

Comment: DON'T DO THIS! You're basically opening your machine to being hacked when you use that flag! Run a server locally. It's as easy as `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` then going to `http://localhost:8000/`. Please Please PLEASE don't spread this bad info.

Comment: I wish Chrome added a setting to solve this. Flash solved this many years ago by being able to define specific folders as "working" folders.

Comment: I mean, it's sad that a newbie needs to know of/install python and know how execute command lines to be able to play with all this...